# Rest API post request not working in Postman for Mac and Ubuntu but working in Windows only

Tags: wcf-data-services, postman

API: http://115.249.4.198:8288/Services/Common/prospectService.svc/IosAddLead

Request Body:

```
{
    "baseEntity":{
        "BaseDBName":"BuddyCRMDB_001",
        "BaseSubscriptionID":"Buddy_001",
        "CustomEditId":0,
        "BaseUserID":1
    },
    "CustomerEntity":{
        "tradingFields":[
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Account Profile",
                "FieldNameMaster":"AccountProfile",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":19,
                "Value":1
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Contact Frequency",
                "FieldNameMaster":"ContactFrequency",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":22,
                "Value":3
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Lead Source",
                "FieldNameMaster":"LeadSource",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":21,
                "Value":1
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Date",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"trade date",
                "FieldNameMaster":"trade date",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":4264,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Lead Status",
                "FieldNameMaster":"LeadStatus",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":48,
                "Value":3
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Campaign11",
                "FieldNameMaster":"CampaignID",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":44,
                "Value":5
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Other Supplier",
                "FieldNameMaster":"OtherSupplier",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":27,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"DropDown",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"BudgetYear StartDate",
                "FieldNameMaster":"BudgetYearStartDate",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":24,
                "Value":0
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Industry",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Industry",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":28,
                "Value":0
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Numeric",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"MX System",
                "FieldNameMaster":"AnnualRevenue",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":29,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Numeric",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Credit Terms",
                "FieldNameMaster":"CreditTerms",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":32,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Numeric",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Credit Limit",
                "FieldNameMaster":"CreditLimit",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":33,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"DropDown",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Usual Spend Date",
                "FieldNameMaster":"UsualSpendDate",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":25,
                "Value":0
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"trade drop",
                "FieldNameMaster":"trade drop",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":3263,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Numeric",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"trade numeric",
                "FieldNameMaster":"trade numeric",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":4265,
                "Value":""
            }
        ],
        "RecordId":0,
        "masterFields":[
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Company name",
                "FieldNameMaster":"CompanyName",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":4,
                "Value":"test new "
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Range",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Range",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":1235,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"lead drop",
                "FieldNameMaster":"lead drop",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":3259,
                "Value":"Three"
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Owner",
                "FieldNameMaster":"OwnerID",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":6,
                "Value":1
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Website",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Website",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":8,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Twitter",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Twitter",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":9,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Facebook",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Facebook",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":10,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Building",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Building",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":11,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Street",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Street",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":12,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"City",
                "FieldNameMaster":"City",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":13,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"ZipCode",
                "FieldNameMaster":"ZipCode",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":36,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"State",
                "FieldNameMaster":"State",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":34,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"DropDown",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Country",
                "FieldNameMaster":"CountryID",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":35,
                "Value":0
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Phone",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Phone",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":37,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Date",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"lead date",
                "FieldNameMaster":"lead date",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":3260,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Lead text",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Lead text",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":3258,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Numeric",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"lead numeric",
                "FieldNameMaster":"lead numeric",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":3261,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Testdroppp",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Testdroppp",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":false,
                "ID":4273,
                "Value":""
            }
        ],
        "BasicContactList":[
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Dropdown",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Title",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Title",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":14,
                "Value":3
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"First Name",
                "FieldNameMaster":"FirstName",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":15,
                "Value":"asdfasd"
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":true,
                "FieldName":"Last Name",
                "FieldNameMaster":"LastName",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":16,
                "Value":"asdasdasd"
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Job Title",
                "FieldNameMaster":"JobTitle",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":17,
                "Value":""
            },
            {
                "FieldDataType":"Text",
                "IsMandatory":false,
                "FieldName":"Email",
                "FieldNameMaster":"Email",
                "IsVisible":true,
                "IsExisting":true,
                "ID":18,
                "Value":""
            }
        ]
    },
    "completeAddress":""
}
```

I want to find out why this request is only working in Postman for Windows. All headers and settings are same. Version number of Postman on all machines is the same.

Comment: What response code do you get on both windows and ubuntu?

Comment: Message like : There was an error connecting to http://115.249.4.198:8288/Services/Common/prospectService.svc/IosAddLead or we can say a timeout like situation.

Comment: And in windows i am getting json response which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you get a timeout error on ubuntu. Verify that you can actually connect to the internet on you ubuntu machine. Try this.

```
ping -c 10 somesite.net
```

Are you behind any firewalls? Do you need to set proxy on your ubuntu system. Compare the proxy settings of your windows system with your ubuntu system.

Comment: No This is not the case

Comment: You know you can check the http error status on postman's response box. Is it 504 on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right it was because of Firewall setting. but very strange.
Thanks Everything is working fine now.